# Removing TTL expired keys in Flink Mapstate

Tags: apache-flink

I need the ability to remove old keys from map state which are older than a fixed amount of time.
I currently keep the timestamps of each event in the the key state map, and I'd like to have an ansyncronous process which will remove these stale keys.

I'm using RocksDB as state backend, and I don't think that the Java API of RocksDB supports the open with TTL as noted [here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Time-to-Live).

So my questions are:

- Is it at all possible to have an async thread that has access to the Mapstate since it runs in an operator function?
- Is there a better practice in this case?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

One straightforward approach for expiring state in Flink is to use a [`ProcessFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html) operator to hold the state. You can then use a timer (either a processing time timer or an event time timer, depending on what makes sense for your application) and clear the state in the `onTimer` method.

Comment: Flink's Table API shows an example how state cleanup can look like: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-libraries/flink-table/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/aggregate/ProcessFunctionWithCleanupState.scala

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick responses. Your suggested solution is not bad at all, however the only thing I'm missing is that the ProcessFunction does not seem to shoot the OnTimer callback in an Async way (am I right?.

Comment: For event-time timers, the OnTimer callback gets called in the same thread that's processing stream elements, as it processes the watermark that triggers the timer. For process-time timers, there's a separate thread that implements the timer service.

Answer (score 0):

As Flink 1.6.0 version, state TTL feature has been implemented. It allows to explicitly define TTL for records in state backend. The catch is that removal of key happens lazy when keys are getting read. If the key is not accessed it will stay there. The limitation most likely be removed in future version.

[State Time-To-Live (TTL) Flink Documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl)

[State TTL for Apache Flink: How to Limit the Lifetime of State](https://data-artisans.com/blog/state-ttl-for-apache-flink-how-to-limit-the-lifetime-of-state)